# SQL Server:sum rows by year and name the row value as 'current' for current year and 'previous' for last year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql server and I want to sum a particular row for this year 2018 and for last year i.e. add data from jan 2018 to jun 2018 similarly for 2017 as well.

This is how I want the output:

[image]

Basically I want the year to date calculations for this problem, and the values column should be added for a particular year, I have given the months as it is my requirement to check if it falls within the month we are in, for example june. The data will be populated every month and thus I want the requirement to get it dynamically.

Comment: You should post your input/output as text not as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you close:

```
 SELECT row_number() over (order by year desc) as [S.No],
     SUM([values]) as Total, year
 FROM [table]
 GROUP BY Year
```

Comment: but I will not get the current and previous year

Comment: That would be just a matter of renaming the years. Setting 'current' = datepart(year,getdate()) and 'previous' = datepart(year,getdate())-1

Would be easiest to make a new column to avoid datatype conversion. idk if I'm supposed to put code here but:

alter table [table]
add year_description varchar(10)

update [table]
set year_description = (CASE when year = datepart(year,getdate()) then 'current' when year = datepart(year,getdate())-1 then 'previous' end)

Comment: It does get both years from the sample data.